# how to manage memory with using properties

Tags: ios, memory-management, memory-leaks

my.h file

```
@interface myObject : NSObject {
    NSMutableDictionary *myDictn ;
}
```

i have a property

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableDictionary *myDictn ;
```

then in .m File

i have a allocated it from id

```
- (id)init {
    if (self=[super init]) {
        myDictn= [NSMutableDictionary  alloc]init];
    }
}
```

my Question is i have mentioned Retain in Property and i have allocated memory also (**is Retain Count goes to 2 in (id)init** )
so how to manage memory in this case ?
i am new to this so dnt have much idea regarding memory management .

one more thing if i have a `method x` in my code and i also allocated memory to `myDictn` then in that case also how can i use release .?? 
Thanks in Advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to initialize a retained property is:

```
NSMutableDictionary *newDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
self.myDictn = newDict;
[newDict release];
```

or alternatively:

```
self.myDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
```

The first method makes sure not to increase the already retained property's retain count by performing alloc,init (an action that increments retain count) on a temporary object.

The second method uses a convenience method for obtaining an autoreleased instance of the dictionary.

Comment: well yup this sounds cool , and i think above code will be same for every function function where i wish to allocate memory to my Object. One  thing more can you suggest , that if for using property var , every time do i need to allot memory to it ?

Answer (score 0):

You should first refer to [*Cocoa Fundamentals Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW39). Then, if you're targeting iOS > 4.3, you can rely on [Automatic Reference Counting](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html) for memory management. But be sure to understand the base concepts and read the fundamental guide or you'll waste a lot of time programming in the dark.